# C++ Defining functions of a class compile error (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class

I am just starting an assignment and am beginning with defining the functions of the class in the "Distance.h" tab and although I am pretty sure my functions are initialized correctly, I am still getting compiler errors saying that "definition not found." I used an online tutor and he ran it on his computer and did not get any errors, although he was not any further help with me fixing this issue. Does anyone know what I am supposed to do in this situation as this is my only computer or if anyone can tell me if I actually am just coding wrong.

Here is my "Distance.h":

```
#pragma once

class Distance
{
    private:
        long length;

    public:
        // Transformers
        void setLength(long newLength);
        void setFeet(int newFeet);

        // Observors
        long getLength();
        int getFeet();
        int getInches();
        double getLengthInFeet();
};
```

Comment: Do you also have a Distance.cpp?

Comment: You've supplied the *declaration* of the functions. What the compiler is complaining about is that it can't find the *definition*. The declaration is the function's "signature". The definition is the code for the function.

Comment: My distance.cpp so far is just:
#include "Distance.h"

Comment: And my source.cpp is:                                                #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Distance.h"

main()
{
 // TODO: Define 1 Distance object: dist1
 Distance dist1;


 // TODO: Call the setLength member function to store a
 // length in dist1
 setLength.dist1();

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your class methods. For instance:

```
#pragma once

class Distance
{
  private:
    long length;

  public:

    //Transformers
    void setLength(long newLength){
    // TODO: define your method here
    // For instance: length = newLength;
    }
    void setFeet(int newFeet){
    // TODO: define your method here
    }

    //Observors
    long getLength(){
    // TODO: define your method here
    }
    int getFeet(){
    // TODO: define your method here
    }
    int getInches(){
    // TODO: define your method here
    }
    double getLengthInFeet(){
    // TODO: define your method here
    }
};
```

Comment: To add: since you mentioned you do have a Distance.cpp, you should write your method definitions in there.